# c++ defining function using #define macro to check com result

Tags: c++, macros, predefined-macro

So I'm working on a windows application and I've decided to write several helper functions to check the HRESULT returned by any com-related function when it is called. I'm trying to define those functions into a macro #define block but I'm really not sure what is the proper syntax. Here are two functions in #define block and the second one gives compiler error when other parts of my program calls it.

```
#ifndef COMUTILITIES
#define COMUTILITIES
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <AtlConv.h>


#define COM_RESULT_CHECK( ret )  \
    if ( ret != S_OK ) {    \
    std::stringstream ss;   \
    ss << "failed " #ret " " << std::hex << ret << std::endl;   \
    throw std::runtime_error( ss.str().c_str() );           \
    }

#define TO_STRING( ret )  \
    _com_error err(ret);   \
    LPCTSTR errMsg = err.ErrorMessage();  \
    std::string s = CT2A( errMsg );    \
    return s;   \

#endif // COMUTILITIES
```

Basically my goal is simple. The first function checks the return code of a com function. If it's not S_OK, then throws an error. The second one tries to convert the error code into a human-readable string and return it. Here are the error I got(the ide I'm using is qt creator but that doesn't matter):
[image]

It says _com_error is used illegally, and other errors I believe were caused by the bad syntax in the #define block. Can someone point out what's wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Have you thought about using [`std::system_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/system_error)?

Comment: Have you considered inline functions instead? They tend to be much easier to debug than macros

Comment: Functions and macros are entirely different things.

Comment: Post the code which is using these macros

Answer (score 3):

A define macro tells the preprocessor to replace what is defined with it's definition.
So if you go

```
#define SAMPLE_TEXT 5
```

the preprocessor will replace all `SAMPLE_TEXT`s with 5.
Macro functions are a little bit more complicated. So if you go

```
#define MACROFUN(a, b) a + b
```

the preprocessor will replace all `MACROFUN(a, b)` with `a+b`, and not with (a+b) or with the result of expression. So, going `2 * MACROFUN(3,3)` will result in 9 (2 * 3 + 3 = 9, not 2 * 6 = 12). Preprocessor is just doing it's job pasting contents of macrofunction with replacing a, b with arguments without evaluating any values.

Returning to original question, to define a macrofunction you need here, you should probably go

```
#define TO_STRING( ret )  (std::string(CT2A(_com_error(ret).ErrorMessage())))
```

Consider avoiding using macros here and making those macrofunctions just regular functions. Let the compiler decide weather to inline them or not.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: It actually does answer the question quite well.

Comment: @CrazyEddie - "why doesn't this code compile?" "Well, here's some different code that does compile." Yes, it's reasonable to say that the approach doesn't work well, but I don't see that in here anywhere. Just a ramble about preprocessing and a code example.

Comment: thanks. it solves the compilter problem.. Just put it inline then everything is fine.

Comment: @CalvinHu If you really think it helps - upwote it. If you think it solves the problem - mark as solution :)

Comment: Wht is if did something like #define food(a)           and not give it value to be replaced